# write.foreign gives "invalid multibyte string 1" error with large data.table, but not small data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` DT with around 35,000,000 rows, the first few of which are

```
>head(DT,3)
1:       NA     00000003787             NA        20.63562             618402
2:       NA     00000005409             NA        20.62192             618402
3:       NA     00000017206             NA        27.04658             618402

1:              TRUE               NA              NA
2:              TRUE               NA              NA
3:              TRUE          (50,55]              NA
```

When I call

```
>write.foreign(DT, sasCsvName, sasCodeName, package="SAS",
              libpath=dirname(sasDataName), dataname=basename(sasDataName))
```

where `sasCsvName, sasCodeName, sasDataName` are strings for the respective files, I get the error

```
Error in FUN(c(",\"00000003787\",,20.635616438,618402,1,,", ",\"00000005409\",,20.621917808,618402,1,,",  :
  invalid multibyte string 1
Calls: writeSasData ... do.call -> writeForeignSAS -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN
```

However, when I make the call

```
>write.foreign(DT[1:10^6,], sasCsvName, sasCodeName, package="SAS",
                  libpath=dirname(sasDataName), dataname=basename(sasDataName))
```

everything works great.

I suspected that the problem is coming from too much data, but I'm not really sure.  To test this theory, I counted the number of characters in the .csv file output by `write.foreign` with `DT` as the argument and got 2,347,252,209.  This is over `2^31-1` so I thought that this might be causing my problems. However, I tried

```
>write.foreign(DT[1:10^7,], sasCsvName, sasCodeName, package="SAS",
                      libpath=dirname(sasDataName), dataname=basename(sasDataName))
```

and I received the same invalid multibyte string error even though the character count in the .csv file output by `write.foreign` is only 655,660,050.

I'm pretty much all out of ideas here, so any insight to the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To ask the obvious, what happens when you do `write.foreign(DT[1:1,], ...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution which *should* solve your problem.  You can remove all non-alphanumeric characters from your data table `DT` and call `write.foreign` afterwards.

```
DT <- data.frame(sapply(DT, function(x) {
                                x <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "", x)
                            }))
```

Then you can continue by making your call:

```
write.foreign(DT[1:10^6,], sasCsvName, sasCodeName, package="SAS",
              libpath=dirname(sasDataName), dataname=basename(sasDataName))
```

The `invalid multibyte string 1` error seems to be caused by an encoding problem, based on what I have seen elsewhere on Stack Overflow.  Removing the troublesome characters should get around it.

Comment: I tried this, but it's taking a very long time and using a lot of RAM on a shared server.  Before `write.foreign` crashes it writes the .csv file it uses to import to SAS.  Should I be able to detect the troublesome character in that .csv (using grep or some such)?  If not, I'll try your solution tomorrow evening when nobody is on the server.  Thanks very much for your suggestion.

Comment: I was hoping that `write.foreign` would allow an encoding to be specified as it basically wraps around `write.table`.  But alas, there does not appear to be such a parameter.

Comment: I didn't actually run your entire solution, but you were completely correct about the problem being a troublesome character in the original data.  After some work I was able to track down the offending entries.  I was completely on the wrong track in my thinking, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Josh Funny you say this, because I was also planning to mention that life would be much easier for you if you remove the troublesome characters before bringing tbe data into R.  Glad you fixed your problem.